# Html5 interpolation-latency problems

Tags: javascript, html, interpolation, multiplayer

I have a node.js server which receives the client position and emits it to everyone once every 100ms. On the client side I have already implemented client prediction, reconciliation and entity interpolation. The problem is that if the latency gets higher, the interpolation is not smooth. There is a constant jitter and the player has different velocities. This is my interpolation code:

```js
function updatePlayers(player) {
    
    var t1 = previousLastUpdate; // timestamp of the previous postion
    var t2 = lastUpdate; // timestamp of the actual position
    
 var tickRate = t2 - t1; 
  
 if (tickRate < 100)   
        tickRate = 100;
        // sometimes the difference is lower than 100(which is the server update rate) and 
        //this also creates jitter                                   
    
    var renderTime = Date.now() - tickRate;
    
    if(renderTime >= t1 && renderTime <= t2) {
        var portion = renderTime - t1;
        var percentage = portion / tickRate;
        
        // interpolate from last known position to actual position
        var interpX = lerp(player.lastX, player.getX(), percentage); 
        var interpY = lerp(player.lastY, player.getY(), percentage);
        
        player.setPrevX(interpX);
        player.setPrevY(interpY);
    }
}
```

So, my question is: how to get rid of this problem? I can't use dead reckoning because the players change their direction fast.

Comment: if you're moving Elements, CSS transitions can help smooth things out.

Comment: I would like to assist with this question but I am unable to replicate your scenario with only the code given. Is there any chance you can provide additional code to build up a test case for this?

Comment: Yes, I can setup a server so you can have a live demo and the entire code too.